# How am I supposed to set up Evolution for local email sending using Postfix?

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, evolution

I want to be able to use Postfix and Evolution to send email between users of my laptop!

I have Postfix set up as a Local Only mail server, and have the domain named as penguin.local.

Is there a way that I should be able to use the options dialog to set it up using postfix?[image: Evolution Account Settings, showing custom options with "mutt" as custom binary and "%R" as custom arguments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using the default `sendmail` binary and its parameters and *not* configuring custom paths or parameters at all.

Comment: Is there a way to do that using postfix? When I tried to use apt to sendmail, it did not work.

Comment: Yes, literally by using the `sendmail` binary that comes with postfix. (All mail systems imitate the same mail submission interface the original Sendmail had.)